# Reshape LSTM Layer Input Tensorformat

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, reshape

I have a table with **4700 rows** and **50 columns**. The last **3 columns** should be predicted.
How do I have to set up my **X** and my **y** to be able to enter it in an LSTM layer?

> X = (?, ?, ?)
>
> y = (?, ?)

I already tried to solve the issue but if I enter the following I get an error

> X = (1, 4700, 47)
>
> y = (4700, 3)

Thank you for any help